# C# Asynchronous Chat Server

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, server, chat

I'm trying to build an Asynchronous Chat Server and this is what I got so far:

Server

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

public class StateObject
{
    public Socket workSocket = null;
    public const int BufferSize = 1024;
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
}

public class AsynchronousSocketListener
{
public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

public AsynchronousSocketListener()
{
}

public static void StartListening()
{
    byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];
    IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
    IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);
    Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    try
    {
        listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
        listener.Listen(100);

        while (true)
        {
            allDone.Reset();
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
            listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),listener);
            allDone.WaitOne();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
    Console.Read();

}

public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    allDone.Set();
    Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);
    StateObject state = new StateObject();
    state.workSocket = handler;
    handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
}

public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    String content = String.Empty;
    StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handler = state.workSocket;
    int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

    if (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));
        content = state.sb.ToString();
        if (content.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("Read {0} bytes from socket. \n Data : {1}",content.Length, content);
            Send(handler, content);
        }
        else
        {
            handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
        }
    }
}

private static void Send(Socket handler, String data)
{
    byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
    handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
}

private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);
        Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to client.", bytesSent);
        handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        handler.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}

public static int Main(String[] args)
{
    StartListening();
    return 0;
}
}
```

Client

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Text;

public class StateObject
{
    public Socket workSocket = null;
    public const int BufferSize = 256;
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
}

public class AsynchronousClient
{
    private const int port = 11000;
    private static ManualResetEvent connectDone =new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static ManualResetEvent sendDone =new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static ManualResetEvent receiveDone =new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static String response = String.Empty;
    static String username = "";
    static int a = 1;

private static void StartClient()
{
    try
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Username: ");
        username = Console.ReadLine();

        while (a == 1)
        {
            IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);
            Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            client.BeginConnect(remoteEP, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
            connectDone.WaitOne();

            Console.WriteLine("Receiver: ");
            String receiver = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Message: ");
            String message = Console.ReadLine();

            String Message = username + "[" + receiver + "[" + message + "<EOF>";
            Send(client, Message);
            sendDone.WaitOne();
            Receive(client);
            receiveDone.WaitOne();
            Console.WriteLine("Response received : {0}", response);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}

private static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        client.EndConnect(ar);
        connectDone.Set();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}

private static void Receive(Socket client)
{
    try
    {
        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        state.workSocket = client;
        client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}

private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket client = state.workSocket;
        int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));
            client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
        }
        else
        {
            if (state.sb.Length > 1)
            {
                response = state.sb.ToString();
            }
            receiveDone.Set();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}

private static void Send(Socket client, String data)
{
    byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
    client.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), client);
}

private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);
        Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to server.", bytesSent);
        sendDone.Set();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}

public static int Main(String[] args)
{
    StartClient();
    return 0;
}
}
```

I'm able to send messages to the server and get back an answer, but the connection is cut every time and I have to reconnect it and like this I wouldn't be able to get messages after I send one. I'm looking for a way to connect my client to the server, send messages in both ways and stop the connection manualy.
Furthermore I'm looking for a way to send messages from one client to another one and to send a message to all clients, who are connected to the server.

Another Question I have, how can I set up multiple ports and let the server listen to all ports? I wanted to open one port for the login and one port for the messages.

Comment: You close your socket in the SendCallback on the Server when you do handler.ShutDown(...); and handler.Close(); I think you need to leave the socket open until the connection is terminated by you. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wahsac9k(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

> I'm looking for a way to connect my client to the server, send messages in both ways and stop the connection manualy.

Closing the connection could be done by adding a disconnect call after the loop: `client.Disconnect(false)`. After some exit condition you simply quit the loop.

It would be preferable to create the client in a `using` statement though, this way it will be disposed automatically.

Comment: Could you give an example of the using statement?

Comment: Take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement

Answer (score 0):

> but the connection is cut every time

because your explicitly close it in `SendCallback`

```
Socket handler = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;
handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
handler.Close();
```

You may call `handler.BeginReceive` instead

Comment: I don't get a response from the server if I call handler.BeginReceive instead.